# NSString initWithData adding extra line breaks

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm using `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` to grab a user id from my server using an HTTP post request. Here is the code that I use to do this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    //....
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data string: %@", dataString);
    //...
}];
```

When I test the request using [Hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) to check the raw output, I get a numerical string such as "13729", as expected. However, The NSLog output will return something like this:

```
data string: 

13729
```

As you can see, two extra line breaks are being added. I can solve this using the following code:

```
NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

However, I would still like to understand why this is happening. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Might be due to the fact that different operating systems use different bytes to mark newline. If I remember right, Windows uses `/n/r`, OS X only uses `/n`.

Comment: What `[data description]` output?

Comment: @BrianNickel I get something like `data string: <0d0a3331 303137>` followed by `void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x1f661810: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.`

Comment: 0d 0a are your line breaks.  Those are coming from the server.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into the server code. Why is Hurl.it showing the raw output without any line breaks though?

Comment: HTTP separates headers from bodies with `CRLFCRLF`, it's possible that you are sending `CRLFCRLFCRLF` and there's a bug in Hurl.

Comment: Thanks the the help @BrianNickel I'm currently working on resolving the server code issue. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, NSString and NSURLConnection are behaving correctly in this case.  The data `<0d0a3331 303137>` starts with the UTF-8 characters `CR LF`.  This is likely due to a server-side bug where the values are getting inserted.

As to why Hurl.it is not displaying that in the raw output, it is probably due to a bug on their end. A normal HTTP response is:

```
{header1} CR LF
...
{headerN} CR LF
CR LF
{body}
```

And your response is:

```
{header1} CR LF
...
{headerN} CR LF
CR LF
CR LF
{body}
```